# How to print name from a list/dict where the first element is T and second is A in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

From the given list of Countries in my Python code.I only want to print name of the countries from the same list, where the first element is 'T' and second is 'A' like-
Taiwan
Tajikistan
Tanzania

I tried below code

```py
for country in countries:
    if country[0]=='T' and country[1]=='A':
        print(country)
```

Comment: First, Taiwan is not a country, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case, if you don't want to explicitly convert string i.e. country name to upper case then here is a very simple method to get the result in 1 line using list comprehension and regular expression as shown below.

> - New to list comprehension, check https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension.
> - New to regular expression, check https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp.

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> countries = ["Bangladesh", "taiwan", "Srilanka", "India", "tAjikistan", "Tanzania", "Pakistan"]
>>> 
>>> new_countries = [country for country in countries if re.match(r"^[tT][aA]", country)]
>>> new_countries
['taiwan', 'tAjikistan', 'Tanzania']
>>>
```

Other usages:

```
>>> # If you want matched country names in caps 
... 
>>> new_countries = [country.upper() for country in countries if re.match(r"^[tT][aA]", country)]
>>> new_countries
['TAIWAN', 'TAJIKISTAN', 'TANZANIA']
>>> 
>>> # If you want matched country names in title case
... 
>>> new_countries = [country.title() for country in countries if re.match(r"^[tT][aA]", country)]
>>> new_countries
['Taiwan', 'Tajikistan', 'Tanzania']
>>> 
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

python string comparison is case sensitive, try changing everything to `.upper()` or `.lower()` first.

also, you can use `.startswith("TA")` instead of comparing the chars separately

try this:

```py
for country in countries:
    if country.upper().startswith("TA"):
        print(country)
```

Comment: ok thanks. That means below code also works-for country in countries:
    if country[0]=='T' and country[1]=='a':
        print(country)

Comment: @AbhishekBhushan, yes, also comparing to `'a'` should definitely work.

Comment: @AbhishekBhushan do you want your search to be case-sensitive? This solution will not work in case sensitive search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression: `re`

```
import re
country = "Tajikistan"
if re.match(r'Ta', country): # match string that start with 'Ta', case-sensitive
    print(country)
```